# Retrieve variable from javascript into controller's function

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have problem with calling this function in my controller named people_amount

```
//function inside people_amount controller
function ajax_amount($cName)
{
    $this->db->select('Amount');
    $this->db->where('Country_Name', $cName);
    $result = $this->db->get('tb_country');
    $amount = $result->row('Amount');
    echo json_encode($amount) ;
}
```

Here's my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    function changeTest(obj){
         //get name from dropdown
         $cName = (obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);

         //call function to get amount
         $amount = $this->ajax_amount($cName);
    }
});
</script>
```

Here's my view

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
         $atribut_blangko = 'class="form-control" onChange="changeTest(this)"';
         $selectedBlangko = $values->ID_Blangko;
         echo form_dropdown('ID_Blangko', $dropdown_Blangko, $selectedBlangko, $atribut_blangko);
     ?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
//show the amount in the form input
    <?php echo form_input('Amount', $getAmountfromJS, 'id="amount" class="form-control" readonly="true"') ?>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is when i select a name from the dropdown, the input form will show how much amount from the selected name. How do i do this? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is `$this` in the line `$this->ajax_amount($cName);`, You cannot directly call a php function from javascript

Comment: i was trying this: var base_url = "<?php base_url() ?> and then doing this to call the function $amount = base_url + 'people_amount/ajax_amount' but the function ajax_amount need a variable to run that is $cName

Comment: @HilmyNurRamdhani use ajax reqest to send data. This is wrong

Comment: you need to setup the ajax call in **onchange** method